# Dataset for Least Angle Regression

Tags: regression, dataset, lars, underdetermined, high-dimensional

I have [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-angle_regression) that least angle regression is good for high dimensional data. I didn't actually understand the meaning of high dimensional data, so does this mean $p>>n$ case?

And does anyone know any good dataset with such properties on which we can compare the performance of lars with say least squares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"High dimensional" means there are many predictor / explanatory variables.  It does not have to mean that there are more variables than observations.  The latter is an additional problem, but with a sufficient number of variables, there can be concerns for the analysis and/or model building process even if there are lots of observations.  For example, models with lots of variables can be harder to interpret, and [multicollinearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) is more likely, even if pairwise correlations are relatively low.  It takes surprisingly few dimensions for some of the paradoxical effects of high-dimensionality (e.g., many points becoming about equally 'close') to start showing up; see this excellent CV thread: [Why is Euclidean distance not a good metric in high dimensions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/99171/7290)

[LARS](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso.html) is just a generalization of the [LASSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_%28statistics%29#Lasso_method), where you progressively expand / contract $\lambda$, the regularization parameter.  This might be a reasonable choice any time you don't know in advance what value is appropriate for $\lambda$.  LARS isn't the only option when you don't know what $\lambda$ to use, however.  You could also search over possible $\lambda$ values via cross-validation.

Certainly in the case where $p>>n$ you will need to do something other than straight OLS regression with all of your available variables, because OLS will fail in that situation.  You don't have to use a LASSO variant (e.g., LARS), however.  For instance, you could run a Principal Components Analysis (PCA) and extract $k$ PCs, where $k<<n$, and then use OLS.  Which of these (or other) options is best will depend on the situation and your goals.