# Potential applications of a result (by Beyer et al) on distance concentration and meaningless nearest neighbors in high dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-nearest-neighbour, high-dimensional, application

My question is motivated by [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253344/generating-a-high-dimensional-dataset-where-nearest-neighbor-becomes-meaningless), and self-study of the paper "[When is nearest neighbor meaningful?](https://cis.temple.edu/%7Evasilis/Courses/CIS750/Papers/beyer99when_17.pdf)", where the authors show the following

**Theorem 1:** Let $X^{(d)} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a sequence of random vectors so that $\frac{||X^{(d)}||}{\mathbb{E}||X^{(d)}||} \to_{p}1 \iff Var\left[\frac{||X^{(d)}||}{\mathbb{E}||X^{(d)}||}\right] \to 0, d \to \infty.$ Then for any given $n \in \mathbb{N},$ and the random sample $\{X_1^{(d)} \dots X_n^{(d)}\}$ generated by $X^{(d)},$ the ratio

$$ \frac{max_{1 \le i \le n}||X_n^{(d)}||}{min_{1 \le i \le n}||X_n^{(d)}||}\to_{p} 1, d \to \infty.   $$

Roughly speaking, the theorem shows that if the the norm of the random vector $X^{(d)}$ "**behaves more deterministically**" (i.e. $\frac{||X^{(d)}||}{\mathbb{E}||X^{(d)}||} \to_{p}1,$) then the nearest neighbor of the origin loses it meaning (i.e. the maximum dist divided by minimum distance to the origin converges in probability to $1.$)

Also of relevance, is a family of examples that satisfies the hypothesis of the above Theorem 1, which is given in this paper "[Concentration of Fractional Distances (Wertz. et. al.)](https://perso.uclouvain.be/michel.verleysen/papers/tkde07df.pdf)", which basically states that (see its Theorem 5, P. 878)

**Theorem 2:** If $X^{(d)}=(X_1 \dots X_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a $d$ -dimensional random vector with iid components, then $\frac{||X^{(d)}||}{\mathbb{E}||X^{(d)}||} \to_{p}1.$

*If we combine the above two theorems, we can infer that:

**Corollary:** *For data generated by features that're iid, then the norm "behaves more deterministically" (explained above) in high dimensions (Theorem 2), hence by Theorem 1, the nearest neighbor of the origin loses its meaning in high dimensions.*

N.B. assume below tat we're only considering Euclidean distances, not fractional etc. We do this because Euclidean distances are more amenable to manifold learnign or do linear algebraic computations (e.g. it's easy to transform dstances into inner products.)

**I'm looking for a *practical application* of this corollary or the above two theorems, in terms of *clustering* and *classification***, where we use nearest neighbor. ***To be more specific, can we use this theorem or the corollary above as a "warning step" before performing, say [kNN or 1-NN classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#:%7E:text=In%20pattern%20recognition%2C%20the%20k,examples%20in%20the%20feature%20space.)? So, let's say that we've an idea (maybe after some normality tests) that the data is generated by a normal random vector whose covariance matrix is almost diagonal , then the features are almost iid (thus *almost* satisfying the hypothesis of Theorem 2 above), and hence we can apply Theorem 2 first and then Theorem 1, to conclude beforehand that the nearest neighborhood classifier is not going to give us good results, without actually computing the maximum and minimum distances.*** *This is just an idea, but are there any other practical applications where we can use the above two theorems?*

Comment: don't use Euclidian norm in high dimensions. that's the practical use. are you looking for something beyond this?

Comment: @Aksakal The suggestion for not using the Euclidean distance follows from Corollary 2 of https://www.researchgate.net/publication/30013021_On_the_Surprising_Behavior_of_Distance_Metric_in_High-Dimensional_Space, where they shows that while using $L^p, p<2$ metric, the difference between max and min dist go to infty, where for Euclidean dist, it stays bounded. However, I'm not sure for certain practical purposes (e.g. manifold learning), we can use those metrics. With that said, my question is ore geared toward what the theorem means for clustering and classification using NN approaches.

Comment: In other words, I'd like to see a concrete application of their theorem in an unsupervised/supervised machine learning task that uses nearest neighbor. I tried to chalk out a potential one in the bold italics in the last paragraph of my OP, but it didn't seem concrete to me. Do you know any paper that does precisely that?

Comment: don't use Euclidian for clustering, it can't discriminate between close and far, everything is equally far to it

Comment: @Aksakal Sorry but I don't think Euclidean distance is always going to be useless. It won't be useless if the distance concentration phenomenon doesn't occur, which is very much possible for highly correlated features. The question is more about the use of Euclidean distance itself, and trying to find corresponding applications.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a possible application. After been generated several tabular synthetic datasets I have seen the following: I have used small sample size tabular data (less than 30 samples) and I have generated synthetic data with for example 1000 samples. The relative contrast in synthetic data is much higher than original data. In fact I have seen that this contrast in original data is close to the Ck value (see theorem below).

Theorem 2 (from Hinneburg et al.):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an arbitrary distribution of two points and
the distance function $\lVert \mathbf{.} \rVert$ be an $L_k$ metric. Then,

$\lim_{d \to +\infty} E = \left[ \frac{Dmax_k^{d}-Dmin_k^{d}}{d^{1/k-1/2}}\right] = C_k$

where $C_k$ is some constant dependent on $k$ and $\frac{Dmax_k^{d}-Dmin_k^{d}}{d^{1/k-1/2}}$ is the relative contrast $\zeta_{\mathcal{L}_k}$($\mathcal{L}_k$ is the norm).

Then the metric $Dmax-Dmin$ will converge at $C_k$ when increrasing the dimensionality $d \to +\infty$. $C_k$ illustrates the concentration phenomenon (Beyer et al.).

Example:

Synthetic data created with python library nbsynthetic (https://github.com/NextBrain-ml/nbsynthetic)

[image]

Results:

[image]

Conclusions:

- This can be a prove that generated synthetic has higher contrast and is more suitable for finding patterns and quantify it.
- If Ck values from original and synthetic data are the same ¿does it means both distributions are close? ¿Could me a 'distance metric' to check if synthetic data is 'similar' to original data?

References:

- K. S. Beyer, J. Goldstein, R. Ramakrishnan, and U. Shaft. 1999. When is "nearest neighbor" meaningful? in Proc. 7th Int. Conf. Database Theory, pp. 217–235.
- Alexander Hinneburg, Charu C. Aggarwal, and Daniel A. Keim. 2000. What Is the Nearest Neighbor in High Dimensional Spaces? In Proceedings of the 26th International Conference on Very Large Data Bases (VLDB '00). Morgan Kaufmann Publishers Inc., San Francisco, CA, USA, 506–515.

Answer (score 1):

What makes this tricky when $d$ is large is that the data can obviously be very far from uniform or Normal or iid or anything, but it may still be unclear whether the distribution is 'nearly' $d$-dimensional or whether it actually concentrates on a low-dimensional subset. For an extreme case, imagine a tangled ball of string, where most of the near neighbours of most points on the string are close in the one-dimensional distance along the string.

What I would do is to pick a few points at random, find their distances from each other and from their nearest neighbour, and see if these were close. This takes advantage of the law-of-large-numbers part of the theorem: as $d$ increases, the probability of a random set of points having nearest neighbours near the typical value goes to 1.

You could even compare the ratio (nearest distance)/(typical distance) to what the theorem says, and say something like "We have 50 dimensions here but the nearest neighbours are only about as useless as in 20 iid dimensions".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm really not sure it answers the question. I'm looking for a practical application of the two theorems and/or their corollary in machine learning, e.g. kNN classification or clustering etc. I'm unable to see how your answer relates to that.

Comment: Fair. I thought it was worth a try.