# Mean field variational inference in high dimensions

Tags: independence, high-dimensional, variational-bayes

Is it expected that independence assumption done in mean field variational inference is going to yield on average better approximations for low-dimensional models compared to high-dimensional ones?

Comment: I think so because L$_2$ is not efficient in higher dimensions. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/99171/99274.