# How should I do clustering when I have a mix of single-element and time series features?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering

I'm trying to cluster together different short audio files based on the zero-crossing rate (an integer) and the energy, spectral centroid, and spectral bandwidth (time-variant values).  I've decided to use these time series as features rather than just taking an average and using that as a feature because one of the goals is, for example, to cluster together the audio files which rise in pitch over time but decay in energy.  I'm assuming that K-means clustering might not be the best algorithm here given that it's meant for low-dimensional spaces, and I'll at least need to do some specific preprocessing first (maybe not just because it's a time series but because it's audio).  What should I look into using here for what I'm trying to do?  Should I look into different features?

Cheers and thanks for any help!

Comment: How short/long are the files? What kind of audio in there, and what kind of patterns do you want your clustering to find?

Comment: @jonnor they're drum samples, like a kick or a snare, so usually about 0.5s or less.  I'm looking for interesting timbre patterns or anything that can further categorize these files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** For clustering time-series data, as a baseline, you can try using [Dynamic Time Warping (DTW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) as a distance metric for your favorite clustering algorithm, say $k$-means.

DTW is commonly used in applications like ASR (automatic speech recognition), and other sequence alignment problems. I believe the Python package `tslearn` implements DTW, though I have not used it myself.

### What is DTW?

At a very high level, DTW is a measure of how "aligned" two time-series are, so it can capture features like "rise in pitch over time + decay in energy;" i.e. two sequences are "close" if you can stretch/compress a source sequence in the time dimension into the target sequence. To compute this, let's define $x, y$ as sequences of length $n, m$ respectively, and $\pi = [\pi_1, \pi_2, \dots \pi_N]$, where $\pi_k = (i_k, j_k)$, a tuple of indices into $x, y$ respectively. Intuitively, $\pi$ defines a "path" through sequences $x, y$ by pairing up indices. Then you [minimize the following objective](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/dtw.html):

$$ \underset{\pi}{\min} \sqrt{\sum_{(i, j) \in \pi} d(x_i, y_j)^2} \quad\text{subject to}$$
$$ i_{k-1} \leq i_k \leq i_{k-1} + 1,\;\; j_{k-1} \leq j_k \leq j_{k-1} + 1 \quad\text{for}\quad (i_k, j_k) \in \pi, 0 < k \leq N;\\
i_0 = 0, j_0 = 0;\\
i_K = n, j_K = m.$$

where $d$ is some distance metric (say $\ell_1, \ell_2$). The final two constraints are just boundary conditions that specify that the path $\pi$ must align with the beginnings and ends of $x, y$ simultaneously; the top constraint specifies that indices $i_k, j_k$ must be *monotonically non-decreasing* in $k$.

This schematic from Wikipedia illustrates this quite succinctly:

[image: Alignment of two sequences via DTW.]

We can imagine each location where a dashed line originates/terminates as an element of a discrete time-series; these correspond to the various $i_k, j_k$ defined in $\pi$.

### What about the curse of dimensionality?

Your intuition that $k$-means runs into the curse of dimensionality is generally correct in practice, and often becomes a problem when you're using Euclidean distance (see [this previous answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions) for more details), but the curse of dimensionality is more nuanced than "more dimensions = bad;" it is important to realize that the curse of dimensionality *affects different metrics in different ways.* Very informally, DTW is a metric that is less "susceptible" to the same dimensionality problems with squared Euclidean distance, as it better preserves its "meaning" in high dimensional spaces.

More concretely, using nearest-neighbors search as an illustrative example, under reasonable assumptions about your data-generating distribution, data points tend to become uniformly distant from one another in Euclidean distance as your dimensionality (or in the context of time-series, sequence length) increases; i.e., most points are "almost-nearest" neighbors. DTW does not suffer *as severely* from this problem as sequence length increases. A more mathematical way to gauge the severity of the curse of dimensionality is shown in [Section 3.4 of this paper](https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/60174/TR1377.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).

Comment: How would I go from there?  I looked into DTW and tslearn but I can't figure out how to combine it with single-element features

Comment: That's a good question -- DTW is intended for sequential features, so it doesn't take of combining with single-element features out of the box. Since you have a few time-series features and one scalar feature, a naive solution might be to use DTW for the sequential features and a scalar metric for the scalar features; then, you could add/average the aggregate cost, which should give you a notion of pairwise distance. Essentially, this clusters sets of features independently. I don't know if this is rigorous/optimal -- this is my first instinct, as I'm not too familiar with this area.

Comment: i'll try this out!  it seems like there might be a better solution that i'll try to look for, but i appreciate this in-depth answer!