# How is UMAP a valid dimensionality reduction technique when it uses KNN, which suffers from the curse of dimensionality?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, k-nearest-neighbour, high-dimensional

I have not a found a satisfactory, or really any answer, to the following problem that I cannot resolve myself.

UMAP is touted as an excellent dimensionality reduction technique by constructing a high-dimensional topological graph, and then reconstructing said graph in low dimensional space. However, *UMAP uses KNN to construct the high dimensional graph*. How is this valid? If we're using UMAP to escape the curse of dimensionality by collapsing some of the feature space, why are we uses KNN to do this, a technique *which suffers directly from the curse of dimensionality*?

Any discussion/explanation would really be appreciated!

Comment: It might help to consider what "suffers from the curse of dimensionality" actually means, because it doesn't appear to have any definite implications for UMAP.

Comment: Umap computes distances in the high dimension space (to define the neighborhood of each point) however in high dimension all distances between pairs of points tend to be the same due to the curse of dimensionality

Comment: It seems that people usually apply pca before umap but that seems to be due to performance issues (inherited from habits with t-sne). Anyway applying pca before umap seems a good way to avoid the curse of dimensionality problem

Comment: @maRmat Except applying PCA to equidistant points, for example, is equal to a random projection. So PCA might distort structure in the ambient space anyways, right?

Comment: You can view PCA as a way to find the best projection on a 'principal components' that are linear combinations of the initial variables where the first components are supposed to keep most of the information. So basically, the top n components should have most, if not all, the information. Applying UMAP on those n components, with n being around 30 for instance, can be a solution to the problem.

Comment: I made a similar question (here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/575864/213793) trying to catch the attention of someone who can give a proper answer.

Comment: Thank you! The answer from @whuber was entirely unhelpful.

Comment: @whuber It would be helpful if you could clarify your statement. The curse of dimensionality states that in high dimensional space, Euclidean distances between points become similar as data becomes sparser. This would absolutely have implications for UMAP, which uses Euclidean distance calculations to determine the high dimensional graph.

Comment: To what answer are you referring?  I haven't offered any answer whatsoever.  I am only trying to suggest that you might need to modify your understanding of "curse of dimensionality."  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality, for instance, which starts off by explaining this isn't just one thing.  Then take a look at some of [our posts on this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=curse+dimensionality): they cover a lot of ground.  In particular, your characterization about "distances ... become similar" makes vague, generally false assumptions about datasets.

Comment: I think that @JulianL was saying that euclidean distances are not meaningful in high dimensions (see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/30013021_On_the_Surprising_Behavior_of_Distance_Metric_in_High-Dimensional_Space, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/99171/213793 or https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jonathan-Goldstein-8/publication/2845566_When_Is_Nearest_Neighbor_Meaningful/links/09e4150b3eb298bf21000000/When-Is-Nearest-Neighbor-Meaningful.pdf for instance). The question is then, how does UMAP avoid this issue?