# How does UMAP deals with the curse of dimensionality?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

This question is related to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/555952/213793) which was not answered.

The curse of dimensionality states that in high dimension every distance between pairs of points tends to be the same. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/99191/213793) for more details. UMAP computes distances in the high dimension space to define the neighbourhood of each point. This neighbourhood is then mapped to a low-dimension one.
My question is then, how does UMAP avoid considering all points to be equally spaced and therefore how can it produce separated clusters of points?

I saw that people are using PCA before applying UMAP but the reason for that seems to be more due to computational issues then a theoretical one. The computational cost of dealing with many dimensions and many points was a problem for t-sne but UMAP is said to be able to handle such cases and therefore should not need prior dimension reduction.

Thanks for your help